# How can I save the result of a continuous command?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to append the result of airodump-ng mon0 to a file.

I want to run it once, append, and exit. I can repeat the command each x minutes with sleep and so.

Comment: I had a quick look at the documentation: are you using the `-w` option?

Comment: what's wrong with using `>>` to append the output to a given file? am I missing something?

Comment: @gogoud: yes, that would work only for commands that run and stop.

Comment: @glennjackman  -w works for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I first brought an edit to the question since I thought it was `airodump-ng` specific, but I actually thought of a generic solution (hence the rollback, my apologies).

You could probably use `tee` here:

```
$ airodump-ng mon0 | tee -a file.log
```

But as far as I can see... Using a standard redirection would also work.

```
$ airodump-ng mon0 >> file.log
```

I tried it using `yes` and `cat`, and my file gets updated even as the process keeps running. `tee` seems to do a `write(2)` for every `read(2)`, there doesn't seem to be any buffering-until-EOF mechanism either.